# angular.isNumeric is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just added below code in angularjs controller to test number value,

```
$scope.isNumeric = angular.isNumeric;
```

And I am getting this error

> TypeError: angular.isNumeric is not a function

I am trying to check number type like this.

```
<div ng-if="isNumeric(10)">
   This is numeric
</div>
```

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/49k9cLz1/2/

Comment: Can you show full code?

Comment: `$scope.isNumeric = angular.isNumber;`, There is no `isNumeric` method

Comment: If you actually meant `isNumber` and that has the same issue what version of angular are you using?

Comment: are you sure that your function is getting called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a mistake:

```
$scope.isNumeric = angular.isNumber;
```

Reference: [isNumber](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isNumber)

Comment: @access404 - sorry but what does this Fiddle explain?